# How to parse forms with Mechanize or Nokogiri from a string

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I need to parse the form to get the value of `IW_SessionID_from the HTML I get back, which I can't get to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'pp'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

r = '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE></TITLE><meta http-equiv=\"cache-control\" content=\"no-cache\">\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"pragma\" content=\"no-cache\">\r\n<NOSCRIPT><HTML><BODY>Your browser does not seem to support JavaScript. Please make sure it is supported and activated</BODY></HTML></NOSCRIPT>\r\n<SCRIPT>\r\nvar ie4 = (document.all)? true:false;\r\nvar ns6 = (document.getElementById)? true && !ie4:false;\r\nfunction Initialize() {\r\nvar lWidth;\r\nvar lHeight;\r\nif (ns6) {\r\n  lWidth = window.innerWidth - 30;\r\n  lHeight = window.innerHeight - 30;\r\n} else {\r\n   lWidth = document.body.clientWidth;\r\n   lHeight = document.body.clientHeight;\r\n   if (lWidth == 0) { lWidth = undefined;}\r\n   if (lHeight == 0) { lHeight = undefined;}\r\n}\r\ndocument.forms[0].elements[\"IW_width\"].value = lWidth;\r\ndocument.forms[0].elements[\"IW_height\"].value = lHeight;\r\ndocument.forms[0].submit();\r\n}</SCRIPT></HEAD><BODY onload=\"Initialize()\">\r\n<form method=post action=\"/bwtem\">\r\n<input type=hidden name=\"IW_width\">\r\n<input type=hidden name=\"IW_height\">\r\n<input type=hidden name=\"IW_SessionID_\" value=\"1wqzj1f0vec57r1apfqg51wzs88c\">\r\n<input type=hidden name=\"IW_TrackID_\" value=\"0\">\r\n</form></BODY></HTML>'

page = Nokogiri::HTML r
puts page.css('form[name="IW_SessionID_"]')

a = Mechanize.new
page2 = Mechanize::Page.new(nil,{'content-type'=>'text/html'},r,nil,a)

pp page2.form_with(:name => "IW_SessionID_")
```

The script just returns `nil`.

Can anyone figure out how to get the value of `IW_SessionID_`?

Comment: It should be `'input[name="IW_SessionID_"]'` and not `'form[name="IW_SessionID_"]'`.

Comment: Then it doesn't return anything...

Comment: `'input[name=\"IW_SessionID_\"]'`.

Comment: Cool. Now I get `<input type="hidden" name='\"IW_SessionID_\"' value='\"1wqzj1f0vec57r1apfqg51wzs88c\"'>`. How can I limit it to just the value?

Comment: `page.css('input[name=\"IW_SessionID_\"]').first['value']`

Comment: Awesome! That worked =)

Comment: When asking it's important to strip the input data to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything beyond that wastes our time as we work toward a solution. "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"
and "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to unescape your example HTML string, then search the **input** with the name `IW_SessionID_`.

This sample code works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'pp'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

r = '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE></TITLE><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">\r\n<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">\r\n<NOSCRIPT><HTML><BODY>Your browser does not seem to support JavaScript. Please make sure it is supported and activated</BODY></HTML></NOSCRIPT>\r\n<SCRIPT>\r\nvar ie4 = (document.all)? true:false;\r\nvar ns6 = (document.getElementById)? true && !ie4:false;\r\nfunction Initialize() {\r\nvar lWidth;\r\nvar lHeight;\r\nif (ns6) {\r\n  lWidth = window.innerWidth - 30;\r\n  lHeight = window.innerHeight - 30;\r\n} else {\r\n   lWidth = document.body.clientWidth;\r\n   lHeight = document.body.clientHeight;\r\n   if (lWidth == 0) { lWidth = undefined;}\r\n   if (lHeight == 0) { lHeight = undefined;}\r\n}\r\ndocument.forms[0].elements["IW_width"].value = lWidth;\r\ndocument.forms[0].elements["IW_height"].value = lHeight;\r\ndocument.forms[0].submit();\r\n}</SCRIPT></HEAD><BODY onload="Initialize()">\r\n<form method=post action="/bwtem">\r\n<input type=hidden name="IW_width">\r\n<input type=hidden name="IW_height">\r\n<input type=hidden name="IW_SessionID_" value="1wqzj1f0vec57r1apfqg51wzs88c">\r\n<input type=hidden name="IW_TrackID_" value="0">\r\n</form></BODY></HTML>'

page = Nokogiri::HTML r
input = page.css('input[name="IW_SessionID_"]').first
puts input[:value]
```

Comment: `css(...).first` is the same as `at_css(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do once you are familiar with the tools:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(DATA.read)

doc.at('input[name="IW_SessionID_"]')['value']
# => "1wqzj1f0vec57r1apfqg51wzs88c"

__END__
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <form method=post action="/bwtem">
      <input type=hidden name="IW_height">
      <input type=hidden name="IW_SessionID_" value="1wqzj1f0vec57r1apfqg51wzs88c">
      <input type=hidden name="IW_TrackID_" value="0">
    </form>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Don't do things like:

```
page.css('form[name="IW_SessionID_"]')
```

`css` is used to search for multiple elements that match the selector. It's highly unlikely a form would have multiple hidden inputs with the same name, so `at` would be more sensible. `css` returns a NodeSet, which is like an Array of Nodes, and, as a result doesn't act like a Node:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('p').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.at('p').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

`text` will concatenate the text elements in the NodeSet resulting in a mess:

```
doc.search('p').text # => "foobar"
```

whereas using `map(&:text)` will iterate over the nodes returning their text:

```
doc.search('p').map(&:text) # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Also note that `css(...).first` or `search(...).first` is the same as `at` or one of its `at_*` siblings:

```
doc.search('p').first.to_html # => "<p>foo</p>"
doc.at('p').to_html # => "<p>foo</p>"
```

So use `at` instead of `search(...).first` for clarity.

Finally, strip your HTML sample to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem you're asking about. Anything beyond that wastes space and our time as we're trying to understand the problem.

Comment: "[How to avoid joining all text from Nodes when scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43594656/128421)"